# Kibana filtering keyword count

Tags: filter, count, dns, kibana, keyword

I am using Kibana 6.2.2 to visualize DNS traffic, and I want to filter out data with more than 4 answers, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ww3j.png). However, I can't seem to filter the count of it. I tried using Terms count on the visualization tab, but I can't figure out how to group the answer section per query.